# How to simultaneously analyse and stream RaspberryPi video

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi, video-streaming, named-pipes

I am streaming a video from a RaspberryPi Zero to my PC with raspivid and netcat:

```
raspivid -t 0 -n -w 320 -h 240 -hf -fps 30 -o - | nc PC_IP PORT
```

Now I want to analyse this video on the RaspberryPi frame by frame to do object detection. The Raspi has to react on the object detection so I have to do the analysis on the Pi while I am streaming the video.

My idea was to create a named pipe with `tee` command and read this named pipe in a python program to get the frames:

```
mkfifo streampipe    
raspivid -t 0 -n -w 320 -h 240 -hf -fps 30-o - | tee nc PC_IP PORT | streampipe
```

But this is not working, it says `sh1: 1: streampipe: not found`

My python program looks like the following:

```
import subprocess as sp
import numpy

FFMPEG_BIN = "ffmpeg"
command = [ FFMPEG_BIN,
        '-i', 'streampipe',       # streampipe is the named pipe
        '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',      
        '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
        '-an','-sn',              # we want to disable audio processing (there is no audio)
        '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']    
pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10**8)

while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    raw_image = pipe.stdout.read(640*480*3)
    # transform the byte read into a numpy array
    image =  numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
    image = image.reshape((480,640,3))          # Notice how height is specified first and then width
    if image is not None:

        analyse(image)...

    pipe.stdout.flush()
```

Does any one has an idea how to do this?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tee` command copies `stdin` to `stdout` and, along the way, to any other files you mention:

```
ProcessThatWriteSTDOUT | tee SOMEFILE | ProcessThatReadsSTDIN
```

or making two copies:

```
ProcessThatWriteSTDOUT | tee FILE1 FILE2 | ProcessThatReadsSTDIN
```

Your `nectcat` command isn't a file though, it's a process. So you need to make your process look like a file - and that is called *"process substitution"* You do that like this:

```
ProcessThatWriteSTDOUT | tee >(SomeProcess) | ProcessThatReadsSTDIN
```

So, to cut a long story shot, you need something more like:

```
raspivid ... -fps 30-o - | tee >(nc PC_IP PORT) | streampipe
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. Its works for me like this:               `raspivid ....... | sudo tee /tmp/streampipe | sudo nc PC_IP PORT`, but it has a high latency and works with only 10fps video stream

Comment: How are you receiving the data on the PC? It may wait and build up a buffer. Or you may need to send lower bandwidth (more compressed) data - maybe YUV rather than RGB.

Comment: On the PC I use: `nc -l PORT | mplayer -vf mirror -fps 30 -demuxer h264es -`, so how can I add more compression to the stream?

Comment: With automatic exposure control, brighter lighting means shorter exposures and less noise which, in general, potentially mean more exposures are possible per second and higher compression is more readily achieved.